# Cannot add an element to List() in Scala

Tags: list, scala, element, addition

Can anybody help me with a begginer problem? I wrote a function to check Declaration, but I Cannot add element Symbol() to List env. I dont understand what the matter is.

```
def check_decl(env: List[Symbol])(decl: Declare): Unit = decl match{
case VarDec(varName, varType)=>{
  lookupForInsert(env)(varName.toString()) match {
    case Some(_) => throw Redeclared(Variable,varName.toString())
    case None => {
          varType match{
          case ArrayType(lower, upper, element)=>{
            if(lower > upper) throw SizeIsNotNegative(decl)
          }
          case IntType=>
          case RealType=>
          case BoolType=>
          case StringType=>
        }             
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You say that your problem is that *"I Cannot add element Symbol() to List env"*, but the only thing you do with `env` in the code snippet you provided is pass it into another function. You're going to need to provide more details if you actually want to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Scala you have immutable Lists by default, and you can't "add" something to it. All operations that would modify a list (or more similar, a stack) in Java will result in a *new*, modified list in Scala. Alternatively you have mutable classes like `ListBuffer`, which behave more like Java lists.